# Copy() function can't detect destination path php

Tags: php, json, file, copy

I want to move 2 files to another directory by using copy() function. 
but i get this error:

> Warning: copy(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\cmsphp\creation\uploaded.php on
> line 50
>
> Warning: copy(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a
> directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\cmsphp\creation\uploaded.php on
> line 51

my code :

```
mkdir("../$name");
$myfile = fopen("../$name/info.json", "w");


$first_file = "index.php";
$second_file = "style.css";

$destination = "../$name/";


copy($first_file, $destination);
copy($second_file, $destination);
```

the folder is created and also the file json but the copy() function doesn't work

I also checked the documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) but it's not working.

Comment: Maybe try to replace `copy` with `rename` ? ... though the documentation is not specific, it seems that copy is expecting two filenames, because a small tidbit in the documentation claims: `If you wish to move a file, use the rename() function.`, and since the file is going to another directory, this might be the way to go.

Comment: @PaulT. no actually i have to copy not move the files

Comment: Ok, so then maybe try: `copy($first_file, "$destination$first_file");` instead? ... and similar to the other copy.

Comment: @PaulT. he copied the files but not in the folder that I want and with the name $nameindex.php & $namestyle.css

Comment: @PaulT. i solved it i did what u said + i added a "/" to $destination thank you

Comment: ...ok, but the `$destination` had the trailing `/` after the `$name`, which is why I didn't add  a `/` in my  example.